# OrientationChange doesn't destroy activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a rather commonly occurring situation in Android, which has to do with the previous asynctask updating the activity, whilst the activity has been lost because of a change in orientation.

I have an activity, Activity A.

```
Activity A implements OnDownloadCompleteListener {

    public void  sync()
    {
        new SyncAttestationInfoTask(this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() 
    {
        loadAttestationInfo();
    }
}
```

Here is my asynctask shortened:

```
package com.evento.mofa.backgroundtasks;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Ahmed
 *
 */
public class SyncAttestationInfoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {

    /*TIP*/
    //TO SPEED UP THIS OPERATION WE CAN USE THE EXECUTEONEXECUTOR . 

    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private OnDownloadComplete parentActivityContext;   
    EntityConvert convert = new EntityConvert();
    private AttestationDao aDao = new AttestationDao();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar"))
        {
            /*EMPTY ALL THE TABLES THEN START PROCESSING*/
            aDao.flushTables(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
            syncAttestLocations(Webservices.ATTEST_LOCATION_AR,1);
            syncDocumentTypes(Webservices.DOCUMENT_TYPES_AR,1);
            syncAttestationInfo(Webservices.ATTESTATION_INFO_AR,1); 
        } else {
            /*EMPTY ALL THE TABLES THEN START PROCESSING*/
            aDao.flushTables(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
            syncAttestLocations(Webservices.ATTEST_LOCATION,0);
            syncDocumentTypes(Webservices.DOCUMENT_TYPES,0);
            syncAttestationInfo(Webservices.ATTESTATION_INFO,0);    
        }
        return null;
    }

    public SyncAttestationInfoTask(OnDownloadComplete context) {
        parentActivityContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog((Context)parentActivityContext);
        pd.setTitle("Loading...");
        pd.setMessage("Updating Data.");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        pd.dismiss();
        parentActivityContext.onComplete();
        // findViewById(R.id.the_button).setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

There is something strange with my Activity.

---

- I put a breakpoint on the onComplete callback inside my activity
- I start a progress dialog inside the sync async task.
- As soon as the progress dialog displays on the screen I landscape my device.
- The dialog box vanishes, and `pd.dismiss()` raises a "View not attached" error (I understand that the activity that it was attached to no longer exists).
- The above means that `parentActivityContext().oncomplete` should also throw the same error, however it does not.
- I commented the `pd.Dismiss()`, and found out that the breakpoint on `onComplete()` is invoked? Isn't this strange given the fact that the reference to the activity has been lost at this point?

Please give me insight into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous `Activty` is being referenced by the `AsyncTask` via a strong reference.

- AsyncTask constructed with Activity 1 (parentActivityContex =
  Activity 1)
- Activity 1 "destroyed" and Activity 2 comes into foreground
- AsyncTask completes, calls parentActivityContext (Activity 1) onComplete
- Activity 2 just sits there doing nothing
- Activity 1 no longer has active references pointing to it, is collected

You could try doing your task in a Service and having whatever Activity is in the foreground receive a broadcast, or you could try having your AsyncTask reference a Fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)`. Below is an example of the second case. *Note that you might want to handle the case where the AsyncTask completes while the Fragment is detached from one Activity and not yet attached to the next Activity*

```
public class ExampleDownloadFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        new SyncAttestationInfoTask(this).execute();
    }

    public void onComplete() {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null && activity instanceof A) {
            ((A) activity).onComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks . I would like to take the fragment approach . However currently my application doesn't use any fragments . Just old school activities. Is this an issue or I can still achieve the task with the code you suggested ? .

Comment: If you are looking to support API levels earlier than 10, you will need to include the support library and have your Activities extend `FragmentActivity` and use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Otherwise, you can simply use the non-support library Fragments and FragmentManager

Answer (score 1):

I would do this

Add this line to your Manifest.xml file, this will prevent of calling `onCreate()` when screen rotates.

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

Version above Android 3.2, you also need to add "screenSize":

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

This will prevent activity from restarting on orientation change, and you should not have any problems (except maybe some layout fixes)

Comment: @Muhammad Ahmed AbuTalib no problem :) sorry that this wasn't what you meant